# iPhone keeps connecting and disconnecting from Mac when charging

Tags: iphone, charge

When my I connect my iPhone 7 to my MacBook Air (2015) with the original Apple USB cable it endlessly alternate between connected and disconnected, i.e. charging and not charging. Thus, the iPhone does not charge and even discharge. How to solve this issue?

Note: cables and connectors are fine. the cable works properly when charging with the power adapter. I also checked with other cables (MFI certified) and on all USB ports of the Mac and the issue is still present.

Also, as far as I remember, I had this issue since my first Apple devices (iPod Touch 2G with MacBook Air 2013) and it affected all my iPhones since (3GS, 4S, 7).

I also want to point out that this issue does not occur each time I plug my iPhone to my Mac but only sometimes and at random moments.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is pretty old and was previously discussed on Apple forums ([here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8276949?page=1)). Here are some solutions that could work, disconnect the iPhone before proceeding:

- Reboot both devices
- `sudo killall -STOP -c usbd` in macOS Terminal
- Settings > General > reset Location & Privacy on iOS
- Reset NVRAM/PRAM
- Delete iPhone USB and Thunderbolt Bridges from System Preferences > Network on macOS

Comment: ...also it could be a defective cable.

Comment: ...or a dirty Lightning plug (on the cable) or socket (in the iPhone).

Comment: I tested those hypotheses prior to publish this answer. I added details to the post.

Comment: But have you tried a known good cable? Over the years I've had several cables which work well on a charger, but are flakey when connected to a computer.

Comment: Yes, I tried both an original Apple cable and a (new) MFI cable from a well known manufacturer with high reputation (Belkin). Please, see my updated question. I also want to highlight, as I noted and my answer, that the issue is not new and affect lots of people.